# How to autohide toast in Bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap-5

I am trying to implement Bootstrap 5 toasts in my Rails web application, using the following code...

```
<div aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true" class="position-relative">
  <div class="toast-container position-fixed bottom-0 end-0 p-3">
    <div class="toast fade show bg-danger text-white" data-bs-delay="5000" data-bs-autohide="true" data-bs-animation="true">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The toast shows up, but it doesn't hide automatically after 5 seconds. What's wrong with my code.

My expectation is auto hide toast after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `show` class on the Toast element. That will force the Toast to always display. You need to remove the `show` class, and programmatically show the toast. For example,

```
const toastExample = document.querySelector('.toast')
const toast = new bootstrap.Toast(toastExample)
toast.show()
```

https://codeply.com/p/FFyaYJTHSs